Blue screen after failed Windows 10 update
My laptop froze when rebooting after Windows update, so I had to forcefully power it off. After turning on again, I got a blue screen (PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA). Windows Recovery also gives the same blue screen. I tried to boot from Windows 10 installation flash drive, but even then I got the same blue screen! Then I tried to boot Debian Live, it booted without problems.
After some experiments I discovered that renaming \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD (on UEFI boot partition) allows to boot from Windows 10 installation flash drive. I tried to recreate BCD using bcdboot, it succeeded, but when I ran bcdedit, I got the same blue screen (just by running bcdedit).
I tried to rollback to the previous restore point, but I've got a message saying that I should boot recovery environment from my hard drive to restore. But I can't because it gives blue screen.
Tried sfc /scannow for the damaged OS, but it said that I need to reboot first (I think this is because of unfinished update).
chkdsk and 3-hour memory test didn't find any errors. S.M.A.R.T of the hard drive is fine.
Is there any way to recover the OS? Maybe there is a way to rollback to restore point from flash drive?
BSOD dumps aren't created, maybe I've disabled them.
I don't want to reinstall because then I will have to install and configure a lot of applications (but maybe it's the only way).

If the normal repair methods do not work, you will have to reinstall Windows. Have you taken a backup recently? If not, you should device whether or not you need to expend the effort to recover data prior to doing the reinstall.

I fixed it by resetting Secure Boot settings to their defaults (had to set password to access this option). Not sure why it helped, maybe laptop froze when updating boot parameters and these became corrupted somehow. Never changed Secure Boot settings manually before.
Here's how I came to this solution:
Tried searching more, found this answer, but it didn't help. The command dism /image:F:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions succeeded, but it said that a reboot is needed to revert completely.
I found a full disk backup made about 5 years ago, restored it to another disk and tried to boot from this disk. Got the same blue screen. Either the backup is bad, or there is a hardware problem.
Tried to put this disk into another laptop and it booted successfully. So the backup is good.
Put this disk back to problematic laptop and it booted successfully, too. But after a reboot I got the blue screen again. This time a BSOD dump was made. I tried to investigate this dump on the another laptop, but I couldn't determine the cause.
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22621.3233 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`75000000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`75c2a310
Debug session time: Thu Apr 18 20:36:22.367 2024 (UTC + 3:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:04.174
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
.......Page 444314 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
.........................................................
........................
Loading User Symbols
PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 000000d3`0f232018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details
Loading unloaded module list
.....
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except.
Typically the address is just plain bad or it is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff00314465646, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffff80179b91c89, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 0000000000000002, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : AV.Type
    Value: Read

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 3577

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 3681

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 1531

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 35052

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 89

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY.DMP

BUGCHECK_CODE:  50

BUGCHECK_P1: fffff00314465646

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff80179b91c89

BUGCHECK_P4: 2

READ_ADDRESS:  fffff00314465646 

MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  2

PROCESS_NAME:  smss.exe

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffd185d0bc3ba0 -- (.trap 0xffffd185d0bc3ba0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=fffff00314465646 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=00000000000055aa
rdx=ffffd185d0bc3e40 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80179b91c89 rsp=ffffd185d0bc3d38 rbp=ffffd185d0bc3db0
 r8=fffff80179d2a718  r9=ffffd98456efdd8c r10=000007fe86339e8c
r11=ffffd185d0bc3f00 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na pe nc
Page 8c838 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 8c838 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
fffff801`79b91c89 ??              ???
Resetting default scope

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd185`d0bc38f8 fffff801`75486729     : 00000000`00000050 fffff003`14465646 00000000`00000000 ffffd185`d0bc3ba0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd185`d0bc3900 fffff801`752eeb80     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd185`d0bc3c20 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiSystemFault+0x13faf9
ffffd185`d0bc3a00 fffff801`7540205e     : fffff801`8a230048 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff878f`cb6f9e90 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x400
ffffd185`d0bc3ba0 fffff801`79b91c89     : fffff801`79b8b4fe ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000002 fffff801`8a234b3e : nt!KiPageFault+0x35e
ffffd185`d0bc3d38 fffff801`79b8b4fe     : ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000002 fffff801`8a234b3e fffff801`79cc5028 : 0xfffff801`79b91c89
ffffd185`d0bc3d40 ffffffff`ffffffff     : 00000000`00000002 fffff801`8a234b3e fffff801`79cc5028 fffff801`8a230048 : 0xfffff801`79b8b4fe
ffffd185`d0bc3d48 00000000`00000002     : fffff801`8a234b3e fffff801`79cc5028 fffff801`8a230048 fffff801`79cc5018 : 0xffffffff`ffffffff
ffffd185`d0bc3d50 fffff801`8a234b3e     : fffff801`79cc5028 fffff801`8a230048 fffff801`79cc5018 00000000`00001e00 : 0x2
ffffd185`d0bc3d58 fffff801`79cc5028     : fffff801`8a230048 fffff801`79cc5018 00000000`00001e00 fffff801`8a2355fe : 0xfffff801`8a234b3e
ffffd185`d0bc3d60 fffff801`8a230048     : fffff801`79cc5018 00000000`00001e00 fffff801`8a2355fe 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffff801`79cc5028
ffffd185`d0bc3d68 fffff801`79cc5018     : 00000000`00001e00 fffff801`8a2355fe 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 : 0xfffff801`8a230048
ffffd185`d0bc3d70 00000000`00001e00     : fffff801`8a2355fe 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 fffff801`8a2441d0 : 0xfffff801`79cc5018
ffffd185`d0bc3d78 fffff801`8a2355fe     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 fffff801`8a2441d0 fffff801`79cc61a6 : 0x1e00
ffffd185`d0bc3d80 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000002 fffff801`8a2441d0 fffff801`79cc61a6 fffff801`8a230048 : 0xfffff801`8a2355fe


SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!MiSystemFault+13faf9

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.508

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  13faf9

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_R_(null)_nt!MiSystemFault

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {636dd506-1acb-bac0-a568-0355527c550f}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

Also tried to put the first (problematic) disk into the another laptop. It rolled back updates and booted successfully.
So, definitely, the problem is with the laptop, not the disk.
Tried to load optimized defaults in setup, it didn't help. Then tried to reset Secure Boot settings to their defaults and it helped.
